# Fail to install Vim plugin on local machine by Vundle

Tags: vim

In order to test, I try to install a local plugin as this step:

1. Clone anything useful plugin to local, like vim-fugitive：

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git ~/devspace/vim-fugitive
   ```
2. Add `Bundle '~/devspace/vim-fugitive.git` in .vimrc file.
3. Execute `vim +BundleInstall` in shell.

Everything is done except the following plugin, the log is:

```
Bundle ~/devspace/vim-fugitive.git
$ git clone --recursive '~/devspace/vim-fugitive.git' '/home/USER/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive'                                                               
> fatal: Could not switch to '~/devspace': No such file or directory^@
```

If I did not understand right, please tell me, thanks.

--UPDATE--

I just change .vimrc to `Bundle '/home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive'`,the error log as below:

```
Bundle /home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive
$ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/vim-scripts//home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive.git' '/home/leiming/.vim/bundle/home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive'                                                                                                                                                                   
> Cloning into /home/leiming/.vim/bundle/home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive...^@error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/vim-scripts//home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive.git/info/refs^@^@fatal: HTTP request failed^@
```

Comment: I have not used vundle, but here are some guesses.  (1) if you cloned to vim-fugitive instead of vim-fugitive.git, then use that in your :Bundle command.  (2) Try using `$HOME` instead of `~`.  (3) Check the permissions on `~/devspace`:  according to the error message, it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you cloned `~/devspace/vim-fugitive` but this is not a repository.
So change like this: `Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'` and if you want to work on your local repo follow this: 
`" Git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)`
`Bundle 'file:///Users/gmarik/path/to/plugin'`

You can see the vundle configuration here: [Vundle on Github](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I change the .vimrc as your advice, but the error  has not be sovled as problem details.

Comment: but in Bundle you have to put the repository address like this: `Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'`

Comment: @Luciani, thx, but I think you don't understand my intent. The point is not vim-fugitive but installing local plugin by Vundle.

Comment: @LeiMing I've edited my answer right now. Following the README you have to put `file://` before on your PATH

Comment: @Luciani, I tried...

Comment: Have you tried `'file:///home/leiming/devspace/vim-fugitive'` ? Very strange, on the README it should be fine.

Comment: @Luciani, it worked, but not my plugin which I code. I think the problem is the plugin itself. Thinks very much!